# Average Monthly Report Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2019, excel-365

I am trying to get the average time it takes to complete a project. The excel sheet is constantly being updated. I used =AVERAGEIFS(L:L,D:D,">="&$O2,D:D,"<="&EOMONTH($O2,0)) which gives me you can't divide by 0 and I tried pivot tables and they are not working because I need the grand average. Attach is a photo of my spreadsheet.

[image]

Comment: Does `O2` have a date in it, or just the text `Jul`? You need an actual date.

Comment: Make sure `=EOMONTH($O2,0)` returns what you think it should

Comment: Try `EOMONTH("1 "&$O2,0)`